# Zoom MolecularPlot on protein region

Tags: chemistry

When I import protein and ligand from two PDB files and display them together using Show I cannot see the ligand since it is tiny in comparison with protein. How can I zoom the MoleculePlot on ligand automatically?

Comment: Can you provide example code so that people who want to answer don't have to make up an example on their own?  Otherwise, MoleculePlot returns a Graphics object, so the same solutions you use for zooming in a Graphics object can be used here as well.

Comment: have you tried Magnify, Magnification ?

Comment: I cannot provide an example since I cannot attach two large files in pdb format

Comment: Magnify, Magnification does not work in this case

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Without a minimal example to work with, I can only suggest a general direction.

```
img = Import[
   "http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=pdb&\
compression=NO&structureId=1tf6", "PDB", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Added control labels and axes and box ratio controls

```
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}, {zmin, zmax}} = 
  Round[Values@AbsoluteOptions[img, PlotRange][[1]]];

Manipulate[
 Show[
  img,
  PlotRange -> {xint, yint, zint},
  ImageSize -> Large,
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  Axes -> axes,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, y, z}),
  Boxed -> axes,
  BoxRatios -> br],
 {{xint, {xmin, xmax}, "x interval"}, xmin, xmax, Round[(xmax - xmin)/100],
  ControlType -> IntervalSlider,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Row[{
   Control[
    {{yint, {ymin, ymax}, "y interval"}, ymin, ymax, 
     Round[(ymax - ymin)/100],
     ControlType -> IntervalSlider,
     ImageSize -> Large,
     Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
   Spacer[20],
   Control[
    {{br, Automatic, "Box\nRatio"}, {Automatic, {1, 1, 1}}}]}],
 Row[{
   Control[
    {{zint, {zmin, zmax}, "z interval"}, zmin, zmax, 
     Round[(zmax - zmin)/100],
     ControlType -> IntervalSlider,
     ImageSize -> Large,
     Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
   Spacer[40],
   Control[
    {{axes, False}, {True, False}}]}],
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this code just cut the molecule, but not zoom on it. I need to enlarge the particular region centered to the ligand.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. As the plot range is reduced the remaining image is enlarged, i.e., zoomed in on.